# Not Return New State React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I trying to make this function to add a new state at Redux.

```
  const initialFriend = {
    current: [],
    possible: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  };

  const friendReducer = (state = initialFriend, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FRIEND:
      const { current, possible } = state;

      const newArrayPossible = possible.slice();
      const newArrayCurrent = current.slice();

      const addedFriend = newArrayPossible.splice(action.payload, 1);

      newArrayCurrent.push(addedFriend);

      const newState = { newArrayCurrent, newArrayPossible };

      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But the problem is I can't get the new state when I trigger ADD_FRIEND actions. Anyone can help me?

Comment: try this -> `return {...newState}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating your state keys. Your new/next state should maintain the keys used so your UI knows what to access. Also, you generally want to be in the habit of shallowly copying your entire state object so any state ***not*** being updated is also maintained (i.e. not deleted inadvertently).

```
const newState = {
  ...state,
  current: newArrayCurrent,
  possible: newArrayPossible,
};
```